# Database of student info using array of structures (C language)

Tags: c, arrays, structure

The function computeScore() is used to create a database of max 50 students using an array of structures. The function takes in the student, name, test score and exam score, compute total and then print it out. Input will end when student name is 'END'. After which, the program will compute the total average score or all the students and prints it.

It works fine for when I keey in the first student's info, but I'm having trouble when the program enters the while loop the second time (when I want to key in the second student's info).

Here's what I did so far:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <math.h>

struct student{
    char name[20];     /* student name */
    double testScore;  /* test score */
    double examScore;  /* exam score */
    double total;      /* total score = test+exam scores */
};

void computeScore();

int main()
{
computeScore();
return 0;
}

void computeScore()
{
    struct student info[50];
    int count = 1;
    double allStudent = 0, allStudentAvg;

    while (info[count].name != 'END')
    {
        printf("\nEnter student name: ");
        gets(info[count].name);
        printf("Enter test score: ");
        scanf("%lf", &info[count].testScore);
        printf("Enter exam score: ");
        scanf("%lf", &info[count].examScore);

        info[count].total = (info[count].testScore + info[count].examScore) / 2;
        printf("Student %s's total= %f\n", info[count].name, info[count].total);

        allStudent += info[count].total;
        count++;
    }
    allStudentAvg = allStudent / count;
    printf("Overall average = %f", allStudentAvg);
}
```

Expected output:

```
Enter student name: John Doe
Enter test score: 34
Enter exam score: 46
Student John Doe's total = 40.000000

Enter student name: Jane Doe
Enter test score: 60
Enter exam score: 80
Student John Doe's total = 70.000000

Enter student name: END
Overall average: 55.000000
```

Output I got instead:

```
Enter student name: John Doe
Enter test score: 34
Enter exam score: 46
Student John Doe's total = 40.000000

Enter student name: Enter test score: 

\\Program skipped the input of 2nd student name
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the last call to `scanf`, it leaves the newline still in the buffer so the next `gets` reads that newline.

You can explicitly get that newline with a dummy `gets` call, but it's easier to tell `scanf` to simply read (and discard) trailing whitespace by adding a space after the format:

```
scanf("%lf ", &info[count].examScore);
/*        ^        */
/*        |        */
/* Note space here */
```

Don't worry about leading whitespace (like the newline left in the buffer from the previous `scanf` call) because the numerical formats (and some others) automatically skips leading whitespace. You might want to read [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: I added the space, it doesn't work, it does not read in my exam score now ):

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `gets` to read string. Its a pain! Better to use `fgets`.

```
fgets(info[count].name, 20, stdin);
```

Be careful when using it with `scanf`. In such case these functions read the `\n` character left behind by the previous `scanf` call.
You can consume this `\n` by placing a `getchar` after last `scanf`.

```
scanf("%lf", &info[count].examScore);
getchar();
```

or even better

```
scanf("%lf", &info[count].examScore);
while(getchar() != '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

Anticipating your next question(s):

Replace

```
info[count].name != 'END'
```

by

```
strcmp(info[count].name, "END") != 0
```

You cannot compare strings with the `!=` operator, you muist use the `strcmp` function.

Furthermore :

you declare `int count = 1;` but that means that the first element of the `info` array will not be used, you shoud have `int count = 0;`.

In the while condition `info[count].name != 'END'`, `info[count].name` is not initialized, so your comparision will likely always be false, even if you correct the condition with `strcmp` as suggested before. In other words: you compare if the user has entered "END" before has has even entered "END".

Comment: How can I initialize the info[count].name?

Comment: It's actually not about initializing or not, but you should change the logic of your program. Do the test just after `gets(info[count].name);` and if it's true, then break from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Scanf is causing you this problem..

Use `__fpurge(stdin)` before scanf to resolve your problem.

Instead use `fgets` than `scanf`.

Comment: Note that it's a non-standard function.

Answer (score 0):

sorry i cannot comment yet.in addition to haccks's answer i will like to suggest you that you should use fflush(stdin) or fluahall() before scanf and you should use strcmp in place of info[count].name != 'END'.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not use `gets` to read a string**. It's unsafe because it will overrun the buffer it writes into in case the input string is too large invoking undefined behaviour and most likely program crash due to segfault. The problem is that the last `scanf` call in the `while` loop leaves the trailing newline in the `stdin` buffer -

```
scanf("%lf", &info[count].examScore);
```

This newline is then read by `gets` in the next iteration of the loop causing `gets` to return. Read this C-FAQ [Why gets call is skipped?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfinterlace.html) You should use `scanf` instead of `gets`.

Replace the following statement

```
gets(info[count].name);
```

by

```
scanf(" %19s", info[count].name);  // -1 for the terminating null byte
```

Note the leading space in the format string `" %19s"`. This cause to `scanf` to read and discard any number of extraneous (including zero) whitespace characters lying in the `stdin` buffer. `19` means that `scanf` will write at most 19 characters into the buffer and then append the null byte at the end. This is called maximum field width and ensures that in case the input string is too long, `scanf` does not overrun the buffer which would invoke undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

you can't compare string using logical operator first error, second '' can contains only char means any single character it may be number, symbol etc. These are two problems and some gets and puts even scanf will skip the words so you have to use some times two input predefined functions I used some time because any of them will read.

```
scanf(some input);
gets(some input);
```

any one of them will work I used it personally.